# Inline if else statement to toggleClass with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an inline if / else statement which adds and removes a class:

```
$myvar.length ? $element.addClass('my-class') : $element.removeClass('my-class');
```

Can this be rewritten to be shorter using toggleClass instead of addClass and removeClass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$element.toggleClass('my-class', ($myvar.length > 0))
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes:

```
$element.toggleClass('my-class', $myvar.length > 0)
```

[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) accepts a second boolean parameter which will add/remove the given class.

Per the docs:

> The second version of .toggleClass() uses the second parameter for
>   determining whether the class should be added or removed. If this
>   parameter's value is true, then the class is added; if false, the
>   class is removed. In essence, the statement:
>
> ```
> $( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if ( addOrRemove ) {
>   $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
> } else {
>   $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
> }
> ```

Comment: According to the docs: `A Boolean (not just truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.` so it should be `$myvar.length > 0` or something.

Comment: What happens when the length is greater than 1?

Comment: If length is greater than 1, it is greater than 0 too so it's ok.

Comment: @MattBurland - yup, apparently this parameter is less tolerant than most others.

Comment: @j08691: I was surprised by that too. But in the fiddle you briefly had up, the only value that would not have the class applied was `false`. Both `0` and `null` and `undefined` where being treated as true.

Comment: @MattBurland - Looks like an explicit comparison to boolean (vs truthy/falsy), which is a bit rare. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9cf250daafe806818da1dd207a88a8e94a4ad16/src/attributes/classes.js#L105

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

In jQuery documentation which you can find [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) the second overload method is what you need. Using 2 params, one is the class and the other is the state a boolean value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.

```
$element.toggleClass("my-class",$myvar.length > 0);
```